# Write code that works on Desktop and Android

Tags: java, android, cross-platform

I'm working on a project in Java that will most likely support Android in the future. But from what I know, Android has different classes/APIs than default Java (for example, I don't think android has all of the AWT stuff). So what I'm wondering, is how can I write my code so that if it is running on Android, it will use the android APIs, and if it is on a desktop, it use the standard Java APIs. I have looked into conditional imports, but unlike C++, that doesn't exist in Java. So how is this kind of thing solved in Java.

Here is an example of what I would like to be able to do:

```
int[] i;
if(onAnroid)
{
    i = androidFoo.bar();
} else {
    i = javaFoo.bar();
}
```

**EDIT:**
One thing I had thought of was using a Common class so I don't directly call the APIs. But What I was trying to figure out is how to call those classes of they aren't necessarily existent without the compiler complaining that the classes don't exist.

Comment: if you don't use android specific API and just common API you would be able to cross platform your classes.

Comment: Are you sure the effort is worth it? General theory says not to make unnecessary generalizations too early.

Comment: Of course it is worth it when you for instance create common library, once we worked with BB, j2me and android and we wrote only one communication library

Comment: I mean it was said 'may support Android in the future'. While in your case it is 'common library'. Big difference. Who knows maybe that future never happens so why think of it too early. On the other hand if we are sure then of course. That's why I was asking if there is a certainty (yes/no).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, what I meant to say is that if it isn't too hard, I will support android in the future. It is more than just a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create architectural layers which are agnostic of any particular user-interface toolkit. If these need to interact with the user interface, they can do so through interface types.

Atop those layers, you can create multiple presentation layers with different toolkits.

Porting software to new user interfaces is common. Separating architectural layers from the beginning can cost little. De-tangling a monolith later can be expensive, sometimes to the point that it is economically infeasible for a company. Whether a requirement to port is certain, possible or unknown, it can be a good practice to separate architectural layers early.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I had that in mind, but what I was trying to ask, is how I would go about loading classes that may not be present. But still helpful, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Note - If you build multiple UIs atop the same shared, UI-agnostic codebase, you don't need to load classes that might not be present. Another approach is to build a single UI with a cross-platform toolkit that works on either Android or the desktop. For example, you might find interesting Eclipse RAP, which claims this; I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I'm reading about reflection here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/ and it says that reflection has performance overhead. I am working with games, so I may need to make these calls many times a second. Is there a way around the slowness? Is it safe to use Class that may not be existent as long as it is never used?

Comment: What I mean is that if you code like this:
if(android)
{
 NonExistentType t = Class.forName("asdf);
} else {
 ExistentType t = Class.forName("fdsa");
 t.method();
}
Even though NonExistentType isn't present, is it still safe since it is never used?

Comment: I would look at abstraction before reflection. In both cases, you're going to need superclasses/interfaces that *do* exist. Loading a class can cause its dependencies to be loaded, even if the code that references them is not called.

Comment: OK. Right now I'm using things like "package.package.Class" instead of importing them. Would importing them cause errors or do I have to just keep referencing classes by there full name.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you import them or not. All that *import* does is allow you to use a simple name to refer to the class, rather than the fully qualified name. One thing you could do is use only superclasses or interfaces that do exist, and provide the implementations that use platform-specific APIs only from platform-specific layers.

Comment: OK. Thanks! Just one last thing. What would be the "best" way of detecting whether the application is running on android or desktop?

Comment: Among the possibilities: 1) on top of the platform-agnostic code, write two apps, eliminating the need to detect at runtime at all; 2) configure the apps to start with a platform-specific system property; 3) use reflection to detect if a platform-specific class is in the classpath.

Comment: Well I think that's about it. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to separate your code, but not like this. Your classes need to be designed to separate the code that is platform dependent from the code it isn't. You should focus on keep the core logic of the application in one layer and render the objects on the screen in another layer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding not-necessarily existing classes you can call like this:

```
try {
       MyObject o = (MyObject)Class.forName("org.me.MyObject").newInstance();
} catch(ClassNotFoundException x) {
     // Here you know class does not exist
}
```

Actually, you should do better than this but I don't remember. But anyway similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection can probably serve your needs. There are several Frameworks out there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Frameworks_that_support_dependency_injection